# PHP - Call function from after call to another function in the class

Tags: php, oop

I have this class:

```
class myClass
{
    function A() {
        $x = "Something ";
        return $x;
    }
    function B() {
        return "Strange";
    }
}
```

But I want to call the function like this:

```
myClass()->A()->B();
```

How can i do that without return the class itself(return $this)?

Comment: What do you want to return? You should return object of class myClass to make chain calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve method chaining, your methods from the chain (except the last one) must return an object (in many cases and also in yours `$this`).

If you would want to build a string with method chaining, you should use a property to store it. Quick example:

```
class myClass
{
    private $s = "";
    function A() {
        $this->s .= "Something ";
        return $this;
    }
    function B() {
        $this->s .= "Strange";
        return $this;
    }
    function getS() {
        return $this->s;
    }
}

// How to use it:
new myClass()->A()->B()->getS();
```